# Sum in google apps script for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I tried to make it but... numbers[i] is somewhy 0 but if I Logger.log it, it says there are 14 numbers in there. So I don't know how to fix it

```
function sum(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss1 = spreadsheet.openById("_______");
  var list2 = ss1.getSheetByName("____");
  var numbers = list2.getRange("S2:S15").getValues().map(function(row){return row[0]})
  var amount = 0
  for(let i=0;i<numbers.lenght;i++){
    amount = amount + numbers[i]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in the `for`'s condition: it should be `numbers.length` instead of `numbers.lenght`.